# AttributeError: module 'wsgi' has no attribute 'application'

Tags: python, python-3.x

**app.py file code:**

```
import webbrowser
import time

#!/usr/bin/env python

try:
    # For Python 3.0 and later
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    # Fall back to Python 2's urllib2
    from urllib2 import urlopen

import certifi
import json

def get_jsonparsed_data(url):
    """
    Receive the content of ``url``, parse it as JSON and return the object.

    Parameters
    ----------
    url : str

    Returns
    -------
    dict
    """
    response = urlopen(url, cafile=certifi.where())
    data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(data)

url = ("https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote/AAPL,FB?apikey=d099f1f81bf9a62d0f16b90c3dc3f718")
print(get_jsonparsed_data(url))

country = get_jsonparsed_data(url)
count = 0
for result in country:
    if count == 0:
        header = result.keys()
        for head in header:
            html_content = f"<div> {head} </div>"
        count += 1


with open("index.html", "w") as html_file:
    html_file.write(html_content)
    print("Html file created successfully !!")

    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open_new_tab("index.html")
```

**passenger_wsgi.py file code:**

```
import imp
import os
import sys


sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))

wsgi = imp.load_source('wsgi', 'app.py')
application = wsgi.application
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/stockpee/staging/passenger_wsgi.py", line 9, in <module>
        application = wsgi.application
    AttributeError: module 'wsgi' has no attribute 'application'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/stockpee/staging/passenger_wsgi.py", line 9, in <module>
        application = wsgi.application
    AttributeError: module 'wsgi' has no attribute 'application'
```

Hi,
Everyone, I am new in Python. I have develop a basic application on my local machine. But when I deployed it on A2Host hosting server. I am facing above error when I run my application in web browser.

Is anyone help me to fix above issue. I will be very thankful for that person.

Comment: hosting server (and code `passenger_wsgi.py`) expects script which runs `web server` - ie. using module `Flask` and line `application = Flask(__file__)` - but your code in `app.py` is NOT web server. You have only normal script and you can't run it as web server. Eventually you can run it periodically using `cron`.

Comment: function `webbrowser` will try to open web browser on server and display it on monitor directly connected to sever  - not  on your local monitor. But servers don't have monitors, and they don't even run graphics mode with windows but only text mode. So it can't even start web browser.

Comment: you have to learn how to run web server using module like `Flask`, `Django`, `Bottle` . And you have to learn how works web servers - they don't have direct access to local devices. Web browser sends URL to sever, and it sends back HTML which browser display. And all this work different than in normal script. Web browser doesn't have direct access to variables in Python code - and sometimes it may need JavaScript for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will applogize in advance for my brief answer.  But it has to do with the fact that you  have not established a whisky app.

You need to make sure in your main application file app.py you establish your application.

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    pprint("whoo hooo.  ")
```

I hope this helps.